# Proof by contradiction for edge in tree

Tags: algorithm, graph, shortest-path, proof, minimum-spanning-tree

I have a problem from my textbook that goes like the following; Assume that i have a shortest path matrix `S` that could look like the following:

[image]

And a tree `T` that consist of the shortest paths constructed from the shortest path matrix `S` (like a minimum spanning tree).

The tree has the following properties;
n - 1 edges, all nodes are connected with each other.

The task is then to prove by contradiction, that if the entry `S_{ij}` has the minimum value, then that entry must be an edge in the tree `T`. I don't quite understand what there is to proof. The way i see it is that if we assume that `T` does not contain the smallest element from `S`, then we will have a contradiction at the end, since there will be a path that is larger than the one chosen with the smallest element. This doesn't seem like much of a proof to me, and even if it is, i don't see how I could generalize the proof.

Comment: I obviously don't understand the problem.  The way I read the example is that you have shortest paths S[12]=1, S[13]=2, S[23] = 11.  This violates the "triangle" inequality.

Comment: If I *do* understand the problem (meaning that your sample matrix is invalid), then I believe your logic is correct.  This is a simple corollary with a trivial "proof", just as you've outlined it.  The effort is simply to properly map the matrix semantics to the tree semantics, using the underlying mathematical properties (definition of "less than" and application thereof) to prove the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Since T is a tree, there exists only one path between every pair of nodes. If nodes `i` and `j` are not connected by an edge, than path connecting them has to have at least one more node, call it `k`. Than for `S_{ij}` (length of path between `i` and `j` holds):

```
S_{ij} = S_{ik} + S_{kj} >= S_{ij} + S_{ij} = 2 * S_{ij}
```

Which is a contradiction.